# Resolution Missing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, resolution, display, lcd

I used System Restore to rollback a driver update on Win 7 pro x64 (not display driver).

When the system came back up, the resolution was less than it used to be. I went into both the Windows Screen Resolution dialog and the NVidia Control Panel and the correct resolution of 1440 x 900 is gone.

I went to my video card manuf. site and downloaded the latest driver for Win 7 pro x64 and it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NVidia control panel had an Add Resolution button, so I plugged it in manually and it looks ok. This still bothers me though...

Answer (score 2):

the rollback may have 'nuked' the monitor inf file.

open the device manager, uninstall the monitor and restart the computer.

or go to **Control Panel** > **All Control Panel Items** > **Display** > **Screen Resolution** (or right click on the dektop > Screen Resolution) > **Advanced Settings** > **Monitor**:

clear the box **Hide modes that this monitor cannot display** and **Apply**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to revert Windows back to an earlier version.

After I lost my option for 1536p resolution over 1080p, after fooling around in Nvidia control panel settings too much, I reverted to a version 2 days earlier, prior to my change in settings, and was happy to see everything back in place.